# iOS 9 not supported by Xcode 6.4

Tags: ios, xcode, ios9, updates

The iOS 9 update is not supported by Xcode 6.4 for testing purpose. is there a workaround to connect my device to Xcode for testing. If not can I roll back my update to ios 8.4.1( previous update ).

Comment: Is there a reason not to use Xcode 7.0? It is officially released in the app store.

Comment: ohh! it was a beta just few days back. sorry! was unaware! anyways thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> The iOS 9 update is not supported by Xcode 6.4

You've hit the nail on the head. iOS 9 is *not supported* in versions of Xcode earlier than iOS 7. Just [update](https://itunes.apple.com/gb/app/xcode/id497799835?mt=12) to continue developing.

Comment: "Just update" sounds fun if you have huge project on swift 1.2 and customer isn't ready to pay extra for conversion it on Swift 2.0. 
Unfortunately we have few issues on iOS 9 and need to do "blind" bug fixing without any way to do a proper debug.

Answer (score 19):

There is a way to deploy to iOS 9 devices with Xcode 6.4.  I ended up doing this because I of course had updated my phone right away, but I did not quite want to go to Xcode 7 due to Swift 2 and the lack of support by coacoapods, yet.

Here is what I did:

- I downloaded Xcode 7, but did not install it.
- Instead I browsed inside the dmg file (Show Package Contents on right-click) to **/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport**.
- I then copied the folder named **9.0 (13A340)** into the same location of my current installation of Xcode 6.4.
- Lastly I renamed the existing **8.0 (12A365)** folder to just **8.0** *- I am not sure if this is necessary.*

I am now able to deploy to my phone with iOS9 from Xcode 6.4.

I hope this is helpful to somebody!

Comment: Thanks for the tip! Helped to resolve the issue I had with testing on my iphone

Comment: @ProgrammierTier, would the app approved by apple if uploaded with this additions in XCode 6.4?

Comment: @Javed Iqbal, I don't see why not.  You're not really messing with the deployment target since that is always restrictive on the opposite end of the spectrum (version must be at least x).  Somebody correct me if I am wrong, but I don't think this alteration will change the resulting .ipa.

Comment: @ProgrammierTier, you are right. I have submitted my app last night. It has been uploaded without any warning. Lets see what happen next ;)

Comment: If someone needs that folders from xCode 7 --> see my answer below

Comment: http://developer.apple.com/downloads/ lists all the DMG's, if you wish not to install them via the App Store.

Answer (score 3):

This worked for me to allow me to test my app that was built against the iOS8 SDK (on XCode 6.4) on a physical iOS9 device.

1. Rename XCode to Xcode 6.4 in the Applications folder
2. Install Xcode 7 from the downloaded DMG (don't update from the AppStore)
3. Open XCode 7 and build a test project (it can be an empty iOS9 app) and run it on your physical iOS9 device
4. Close Xcode 7 and open XCode 6.4
5. Build your app against the iOS8 SDK and debug on the physical iOS9 device

It seems like debugging on XCode 7 first updates something on the device and then XCode 6.4 can debug properly.

(This is useful for example, if you don't want to migrate your Swift 1.2 code to 2.0 yet)

Comment: Note that sometimes you need to repeat the process of building app on Xcode 7 in order to be able to keep using Xcode 6.4. For those who wonder why one would want to use Xcode 6.4 when having 7, Xcode 7 is changing some of the app behaviors, and it is easier to use older Xcode than to fix an almost-finished project.